# selecting image for multiple image view from cam or library

Tags: ios, objective-c, image, uiimagepickercontroller

I have 3 `Image views` on my `view controller` (Purpose Before ,During, After) .
i need to select images for each of view respectively .

the didicated method for this task is :

```
 -(void) imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info{
      UIImage *image;
        image = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
        [_imgView setImage:image];
        [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
}
```

but how to notify this method about which button has called the image picker and to select/display the image on view respectively .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a "private" (yes I know no such thing) ivar to hold a reference to the selectedImageView

```
@interface MyViewController ()

@property (nonatomic, strong) UIImageView *selectedImageView;

@end
```

Then when the imageView is selected use this new ivar to keep a reference to the currently active imageView

```
- (void)imageViewTapped:(id)sender
{
  // This assumes the use of a gesture recognizer but you can substitute your usual method
  // of detecting the imageView that you want to edit.
  self.selectedImageView = [sender view];
}
```

Now your delegate can look like this

```
-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
  self.selectedImageView.image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
  self.selectedImageView = nil;

  [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Comment: i have a query , when this imageViewTapped is called ? and why did you  self.selectedImageView= nil ??

Comment: That `imageViewTapped:` was just an example of responding to a touch - you can substitute this for whatever method you have of recognising which `imageView` the user wants to edit. I set `selectedImageView` to `nil` because the interaction with it has finished so there is no point keeping a reference around that may be confusing later on - you don't have to do this if there is still some work to be done with that `imageView`

Comment: @Paul.s Where you are calling imageviewTapped method?

Answer (score 0):

On a class level take a variable that holds the reference of the imageview.

When you are tapping the image, store the tapped imageview's reference into this variable.

Into imagepicker delegate method, use this variable to set image.

Comment: i need some more info , it will be great if you can provide me some code .